# UICollectionView Layout Issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using `UICollectionView` using the flow layout.
I have made a custom `UICollectionViewCell` for the same.
But on running the project the console keeps on throwing this error-

```
The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
 the item height must be less that the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.
```

I have made sure that the size of the cell is correct

Has anyone been able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please add some information about flowLayout.itemSize, collectionView.fram! Crash when rotate or viewDidLoad?

Comment: I have found out that this error comes only when i select the Scroll direction as horizontal.

Comment: It does not crash just the UI goes blank.
This is the size of the cell. 300X460
Collection View frame- 300X480
Layout Frame-300X480
I have taken all these values from the xib
I want the Collection view to scroll horizontally not vertically.

Comment: itemSize > CollecitonView.frame(height or width), check your itemSize and collecitonView.frame.

Comment: Is it because i have set the Scrolling as Horizontal?
Cuz it seems to work fine in vertical scrolling

Comment: This post explains why this is happening and also provides solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39497850/4218640

Answer (score 39):

I found that, using `storyboards`, you have to go into the `storyboard` and click on the overall `View Controller` (the view should be highlighted in blue) and go to the `Attributes Inspector` (the fourth tab on the right side of the screen) and unchecking the "Under Top Bars", "Under Bottom Bars", and "Under Opaque Bars."  This cleared up the issue for me, and it cleared it for my coworkers as well.

Comment: I found that unchecking "Adjust Scroll View Insets" removed the warning. (using Storyboards, Autolayout in cells)

Comment: Thanks Buddy! you just saved my life! It worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me: programmatically added collectionView on a storyboard based uiView.

Answer (score 29):

I've been having some issues when the using a collection view to present full screen view controllers.

Basically at run time, it'll ask for the size of the item and simply return the size of the collection view:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return self.collectionView.frame.size;
}
```

Comment: This is better than my answer if you want to support rotation

Answer (score 28):

I know this is a very late reply, but I have also experienced this.

Inside my view controller, let's call it *MyViewController* I have a `UICollectionView` that is using custom `UICollectionViewCell`s. I'm implementing the method [collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:) where I am returning a item size that is dependent on the height of the `UICollectionView`.

*MyViewController* is made in a storyboard using autolayout to control the height of the `UIViewController`.

The cells look fine when in portrait mode, but did not when in landscape mode.

I solved my issues by invalidating the `UICollectionViewLayout` of my `UICollectionView` inside the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Earlier I had tried to invalidate the layout inside `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration`, but it didn't work. The reason for this is probably that the sizes for all the views are not calculated yet, so we have to wait until autolayout has finished its magic. I refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555275/is-there-an-ios-method-that-fires-when-autolayout-has-completed).

**Update for Swift 4.0:**

```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
  }
```

Comment: thank you! after hours of trying different suggestions this simple solution eliminated my layout warnings.

Comment: This worked for me on a collectionView inside a `UIView`. Been at this for hours and this is the only thing that worked!

I just overrode the `layoutSubviews` method.

Answer (score 18):

Had this issue myself a few times when trying to create collection views with fullscreen cells. My problem was caused by laying out for 4" screen in IB/Storyboard and specifying 320*568 for item size, but running in the simulator using 3.5" screen, which has a height of 480. The solution is to specify your item size in code with something like:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (id) self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
layout.itemSize = self.collectionView.frame.size;
```

This ensures that the cell size is set correctly at runtime.

Comment: Why do you assign size of entire view to size of single cell ?

Comment: I encountered this issue with full-screen cells. Not sure if the OP is doing the same, but this is the most obvious way that you would experience this issue.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using storyboards and auto layout, debugging this kind of problems is really hard...

I had similar problem when trying to display UICollectionViewCell fullscreen on iPhone.

Most of the time issue is with the size of the cell set in

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
```

or directly on flowLayout.itemSize.

But... try:

1. Select the ViewController:

[image: Selecting View Controller]

2. Then uncheck Extend Edges options:

[image: Disable Extend Edges Options]

And now try setting your auto layout constraints.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

That fixed my problem:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.height - 70);
}
```

U can see padding value from top and bottom on this screen:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to set the right autoresizing mask for UICollectionView and UICollectionviewcell.
This fixed my problem for iPhone 4 Simulator

Comment: Also, setting up the autoresizing mask on the cell's contentView (or a UITableViewCell's content view) can help

Answer (score 2):

For me I am using AKPickerView inside of a custom UIView which was giving me a slew of warnings like the ones mentioned here.  All I did to eliminate the warnings was to Un-Check the box called 'AutoResize Subviews' in the Attributes Inspector for my custom UIView.  That silenced the warnings so hard, I thought my logger stopped working.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What caused this for me was that I was trying to set my cells to the size of the superview rather than the size of the `UICollectionView`. Simply replaced the superview frame with the `UICollectionView` frame.

Comment: i was using   CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height:view.frame.height  ) as collectionview cell size , i changed to  CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height  ) , then everything is okay now . (I put a collectiomview inside another collectionview cell )

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I was need full screen cells in collectionView. So I resolved it with this decision.

1. Cell size is equal collection view size

[image]
2. Change in storyboard "Inset from:" from Safe Area to Content Inset

[image]

3. Change "Content Insets" to Never
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same error message, but for me the issue was that when I received new data from the api and tried to refresh my collectionView, the method that called `[collectionView reloadData]` wasn't calling it on the main thread.

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue

> the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.

I solved this issue by checking the values in section Insets.And for fix cell size I have used below code.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);
CGFloat cellWidth =  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 20;
CGFloat cellHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 120;

return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading a collectionView via a container view + UICollectionViewController, you may have set a height constraint on the *container* view which is constraining the height of the collection view itself.  In my case, I found the collectionView.contentSize was taller than the constraint I had set on my container view.

Obviously this is a bit of an edge case but just in case you have a similar setup, I figured I'd add this comment.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to set `Estimate Size` (in the storyboard size attributes pane) for the collection view to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining that the item height is bigger than the height of the collectionView. So it's sticking out.
So you have to make the height the same or less.
Like this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.height, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    
}
```

Using the height for the width makes it a square. This is assuming inset is 0 which it should be if you haven't done anything.

Answer (score -3):

None of the above fixes did it for me.
I fixed it with this

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{CGFloat currentWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width;
UIEdgeInsets sectionInset = [(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout sectionInset]; //here the sectionInsets are always = 0 because of a timing issue so you need to force set width of an item a few pixels less than the width of the collectionView.

CGFloat width = currentWidth - 10;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be incomplete code. Where is return statement? Is it just CGSize(width, collectionView.frame.size.height) or have you changed it?