# the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined, because the cell width is greater than collectionView width

Tags: uicollectionview, ios9, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, xcode7-beta5

> 2015-08-18 16:07:51.523 Example[16070:269647] the behavior of the
> UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: 2015-08-18
> 16:07:51.523
> Example[16070:269647] the item width must be less than
> the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and
> right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
> 2015-08-18 16:07:51.524 Example[16070:269647] The relevant
> UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout:
> 0x7f24d670>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7b377200;
> frame = (0 0; 768 1024); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H;
> gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f24ce30>; animations = {
> position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x7f279d60>;
> bounds.origin=<CABasicAnimation: 0x7f279430>;
> bounds.size=<CABasicAnimation: 0x7f279480>; }; layer = <CALayer:
> 0x7aec9cf0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1024, 770}>
> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f24d670>.
> 2015-08-18 16:07:51.524 Example[16070:269647] Make a symbolic
> breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch
> this in the debugger.

That is what I get and what I do

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView!.frame.size.width - 20, 66)
    }
```

I rotate from landscape to portrait then the console shows this error message only in iOS 9 if anyone knows what happens and if there is a fix for this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have your issue solved?

Comment: nope, its not resolved

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This happens when your collection view resizes to something less wide (go from landscape to portrait mode, for example), and the cell becomes too large to fit.

Why is the cell becoming too large, as the collection view flow layout should be called and return a suitable size ?

```
collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Update to include Swift 4

```
@objc override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{  ...  }
```

This is because this function is **not** called, or at least not straight away.

What happens is that your collection view flow layout subclass does not override the `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange` function, which `returns false` by default.

When this method returns false, the collection view first tries to go with the current cell size, detects a problem (which logs the warning) and then calls the flow layout to resize the cell.

**This means 2 things :**

1 - The warning in itself is not harmful

2 - You can get rid of it by simply overriding the `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange` function to return true.
In that case, the flow layout will always be called when the collection view bounds change.

Comment: I have tried all possible suggestions on the internet and this one is the right answer!!! Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and simple solution! If I could I would upvote this answer 10 times.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.  UPDATE for swift 4: change "sizeForItemAtIndexPath" to "sizeForItem" or it will NOT work, and NOT show any errors.

Comment: From WWDC'18 *A Tour of UICollectionView*, it's mentioned that this method `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange` is called even when **scrolling** the collection view. So the speaker particular cautions you to be careful when overriding this method, since it's called pretty often.

Comment: Here's an alternative solution of this issue which worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53117524/5242940

Comment: This did not solve it for me. I ended up just recreating the `UICollectionView` when the device rotates. It's not like it happens all that often.

Comment: What is the `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange` function. I can't find it for swift

Comment: @Sam shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange:)

Comment: Weird, that didn't seem to help me, It resizes at first but then it gets big again. I have a bountied question on similar stuff if you interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617380/setting-and-changing-width-height-of-uicollectionview-cells-with-pinch-gestures

Comment: This certainly sounds correct, but I implemented this override to return true, set the custom layout class, and ran it in iOS 12.2 simulator, saw it call my override, and still spewed the warning repeatedly.

Comment: Is it possible to call `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange` without subclassing the layout?

Answer (score 64):

select collectionview in storyboard go to size inspector change estimate size to none

Comment: Works perfect. And also tick content view from size inspector for CollectionViewCell

Comment: I have crash a in two iOS Versions 10 and 11, @satish's solution worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But could you explain why this is? I had the default: Automatic, why didn't that work?

Comment: why does this work? any explanation?

Answer (score 34):

**XCode 11**

For me, the reason was that the CollectionView's Estimate option size was set to Automatic.
It seems it is the default behavior in XCode 11.

Hence for me which I loaded the images in the cells, because of the size of the images and the automatic option (which wants to adapt the size of the cell with the size of the image) the cell's width became greater than the CollectionView's width.

By setting this option to None the problem solved.

[image: where the automatic option is located]

Answer (score 27):

I've also seen this occur when we set the estimatedItemSize to automaticSize and the computed size of the cells is less than 50x50 (Note: This answer was valid at the time of iOS 12. Maybe later versions have it fixed).

i.e. if you are declaring support for self-sizing cells by setting the estimated item size to the `automaticSize` constant:

```
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

and your cells are actually smaller than 50x50 points, then UIKit prints out these warnings. FWIW, the cells are eventually sized appropriately and the warnings seem to be harmless.

One <strike>fix</strike> workaround is to replace the constant with a 1x1 estimated item size:

```
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
```

This does not impact the self-sizing support, because as the documentation for `estimatedItemSize` mentions:

> Setting it to any other value causes the collection view to query each cell for its actual size using the cell’s preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_:) method.

However, it might/might-not have performance implications.

Comment: If the covid-19 wouldn't be with us these days, I swear I would travel wherever you are at the moment and hug you so much lol you saved my day man This drove me crazy. Looked at a lot of tutorials for setting up self-sizing cells and even in my own project had them setup correctly, but... they were all over 50pt. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is very obvious now that you've said it! Thanks for providing this answer

Comment: Thank you! This variable is clearly not an `automaticSize`, it's a `standardEstimatedSize`. Why the variable is named that way is beyond me.

Answer (score 13):

I've solve this problem by using `safeAreaLayoutGuide`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: (view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width), height: 80);
}
```

and you also have to override this function to support portrait and landscape mode correctly.

```
 override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout();
}
```

Comment: For me this did the trick. In viewWillTransistion I already changed some sectioninsets because of the island of the iphone 14. And changing from portrait to landscape was ok, other way around it threw in a lot of warnings. Now I call collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() before changing the sectionInsets in viewWillTransistion. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

I am using a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and using its `itemSize` property to specify the cell size (instead of the `collectionView:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` delegate method). Every time I rotate the screen to a shorter width one (e.g. landscape -> portrait) I get this huge warning in question.

I was able to fix it by doing 2 steps.

**Step 1:** In `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass's `prepareLayout()` function, move `super.prepareLayout()` to **after** where `self.itemSize` is set. I think this makes the super class to use the correct `itemSize` value.

```
import UIKit

extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

  var collectionViewWidthWithoutInsets: CGFloat {
    get {
      guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return 0 }
      let collectionViewSize = collectionView.bounds.size
      let widthWithoutInsets = collectionViewSize.width
        - self.sectionInset.left - self.sectionInset.right
        - collectionView.contentInset.left - collectionView.contentInset.right
      return widthWithoutInsets
    }
  }

}

class StickyHeaderCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

  // MARK: - Variables
  let cellAspectRatio: CGFloat = 3/1

  // MARK: - Layout
  override func prepareLayout() {
    self.scrollDirection = .Vertical
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 1
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: self.minimumLineSpacing, right: 0)
    let collectionViewWidth = self.collectionView?.bounds.size.width ?? 0
    self.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: 40)

    // cell size
    let itemWidth = collectionViewWidthWithoutInsets
    self.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth/cellAspectRatio)

    // Note: call super last if we set itemSize
    super.prepareLayout()
  }

  // ...

}
```

Note that the above change will somehow make the layout size change when screen rotates stops working. This is where step 2 comes in.

**Step 2:** Put this in the **view controller** that holds the collection view.

```
  override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
  }
```

Now the warning is gone :)

---

#### Some Notes:

1. Make sure you are adding constraints to the collectionView and not using `collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]`
2. Make sure you are not calling `invalidateLayout` in `viewWillTransitionToSize()`  because the width of an edge-to-edge cell in landscape is larger than the collection view’s frame width in portrait. See below references.

#### References

- [Making Adaptive Forms using UICollectionView](https://possiblemobile.com/2016/05/uicollectionview-dynamic-cell-widths/)
- [Collection view with self-sizing cells](http://corsarus.com/2015/collection-view-with-self-sizing-cells/)

Comment: ill look at this solution, the answer came a lot later than I went out from the project :(

Comment: That works @Hlung, I hope you don't mind, I've added some notes as there are other requirements to prevent errors like these.

Comment: The key for me to fix warnings was to call [super prepareLayout] after the itemSize was set. Thank you @Hlung!

Answer (score 6):

For Xcode 11, none of the above methods worked for me.

It turned out one need to set the Estimate Size to None in the collection view size panel.

see: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123625

Answer (score 5):

Its happens because your collection view cell's width is bigger than collection view width after rotation.suppose that you have a 1024x768 screen and your collection view fills the screen.When your device is landscape,your cell's width  will be  self.collectionView.frame.size.width - 20 =1004 and its greater than your collection view's width in portrait = 768.The debugger says that "the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values".

Comment: @Magoo You can fix it by changing collection view flow layout values for item size. The delegate must consider rotation. As the debugger says, the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.

Answer (score 5):

Turn your collection view's estimate size 'None' value from automatic.

You can do this by the storyboard or programatically.

But you have to calculate it manually with custom layout class or 'UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout' protocol APIs

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

**Invalidate the layout on rotation:**

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

**Have a separate function for calculating the available width:**

*Note: taking in to account both section inset and content inset.*

```
// MARK: - Helpers

func calculateCellWidth(for collectionView: UICollectionView, section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    var width = collectionView.frame.width
    let contentInset = collectionView.contentInset
    width = width - contentInset.left - contentInset.right

    // Uncomment the following two lines if you're adjusting section insets
    // let sectionInset = self.collectionView(collectionView, layout: collectionView.collectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt: section)
    // width = width - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right

    // Uncomment if you are using the sectionInset property on flow layouts
    // let sectionInset = (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.sectionInset ?? UIEdgeInsets.zero
    // width = width - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right

    return width
}
```

**And then of course finally returning the item size:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: calculateCellWidth(for: collectionView, section: indexPath.section), height: 60)
}
```

I think it is important to note that this works because invalidating a layout wont trigger a recalculation of the cell size immediately, but during the next layout update cycle. This means that once the item size callback is eventually called, the collection view has the correct frame, thus allowing accurate sizing.

**Voila!**

Comment: Hi this line got error:   let sectionInset = self.collectionView(collectionView, layout: collectionView.collectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt: section). do u have sample project that make it work. thank

Comment: Hey @LêKhánhVinh, that's because you're not implementing that particular optional delegate method. You can just comment out those lines, I'll update my post too.

Comment: Hi anyway to auto adjust the height of cell base on content instead of return fix value 60?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh yes there is a way to do it with collection views. You can research "self sizing cells" and UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize.

Comment: Only writing view will layout subview method helped me to solve the issue. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can check in debugger if `collectionView.contentOffset` is changed to negative in my case it changes from `(0,0)` to `(0,-40)`. You can solve this issue by using this method

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:)]) {
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After doing some experimenting, this seems to also be tied to how you layout your collectionView.

The tl;dr is: Use AutoLayout, not autoresizingMask.

So for the core of the problem the best solutions I've found to handle orientation change use the following code, which all makes sense:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

*However*, there are still situations where you can get the item size warning. For me it's if I am in landscape in one tab, switch to another tab, rotate to portrait, then return to the previous tab. I tried invalidating layout in willAppear, willLayout, all the usual suspects, but no luck. In fact, even if you call `invalidateLayout` *before* `super.willAppear()` you still get the warning.

And ultimately, this problem is tied to the size of the collectionView bounds updating before the delegate is asked for the itemSize.

So with that in mind I tried using AutoLayout instead of `collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]`, and with that, problem solved! (I use SnapKit to do AutoLayout so that I don't pull my hair out constantly). You also just need to `invalidateLayout` in `viewWillTransition` (without the `coordinator.animate`, so just as you have in your example), and also `invalidateLayout` at the bottom of `viewWillAppear(:)`. That *seems* to cover all situations.

I dont know if you are using autoresizing or not - it would be interesting to know if my theory/solution works for everyone.

Comment: I managed to resolve by invalidating the layout in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
override open func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution definitely works.. Try this code

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) 

{

 collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

 super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

In my case, I had a collection view  and when you tapped on one of the cells, a popover with a `UITextField` opened, to edit the item. After that popover disappeared, the `self.collectionView.contentInset.bottom` was set to 55 (originally 0).

To fix my issue, after the popover view disappears, I’m manually setting contentInset to `UIEdgeInsetsZero`.

[image: contextual prediction bar]

The original issue seems to be related to the contextual prediction bar that shows up on top of the keyboard. When the keyboard is hidden, the bar disappears, but the `contentInset.bottom` value is not restored to the original value.

Since your issue seems to be related to the width and not to the height of the cell, check if any of the `contentInset` or `layout.sectionInset` values are the same as the one set by you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  I fixed this by clearing my collection view of it's constraints, and resetting them in Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it by putting 
`super.prepare()`
 at end of 
`override func prepare() { }`

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this problem for some hours, too.

My `UICollectionViewController` is embedded in a container view, when rotating the iPad from landscape to portrait it showed the error. The cells did resize though.

I solved the error by calling the following in the `UICollectionViewController`:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

The "super" has to be called **after** invalidating the layout.

Additionally I needed to call the following in the view where the container view is embedded in:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionViewController.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This way, the cells are updated after the screen rotation is done.

Answer (score 1):

It is my solution:

1. Remove all UICollectionViewFlowDelegate methods from your view controller.
2. Create your own flowLayout class as a subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

   class ImageCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {}
3. Configure all sizes and other parameters into prepare() method. See my example below.

   ```
    private let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 20.0)

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        self.sectionInset = sectionInsets
        self.minimumLineSpacing = sectionInsets.bottom
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = sectionInsets.bottom
        let width = collectionView.bounds
            .inset(by: collectionView.layoutMargins)
            .inset(by: self.sectionInset)
            .width
        self.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width + 16)
        //self.itemSize - I do not set itemsize because my cell has dynamical height
    }
   ```

4. Set your new class for collection view on your storyboard(or xib).
   [image]

That's all. Keep your code clean.

Answer (score 1):

if you're a using Dynamic Types for fonts, just reload a `collectionView` when font size is changing:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this worked quite well for **`UICollectionViewController`** and animated correctly:

```c
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
       withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    // Ensure the layout is within the allowed size before animating below, or 
    //  `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes` breakpoint will trigger
    //  and the logging will occur.

    if ([self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout isKindOfClass:[YourLayoutSubclass class]]) {
        [(YourLayoutSubclass *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout updateForWidth:size.width];
    }

    // Then, animate alongside the transition, as you would:

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^
        (id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
            [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
        }
                                 completion:nil];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size
          withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}

///////////////

@implementation YourLayoutSubclass

- (void)prepareLayout {
    [super prepareLayout];

    [self updateForWidth:self.collectionView.bounds.size.width];
}

- (void)updateForWidth:(CGFloat)width {
    // Update layout as you wish...
}

@end
```

... See inline code comments above for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Any Changes in UIView must be done from main thread. Put your code of collectionView addition to views hierarchy into:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    ...  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for a vertical UICollectionView I had:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: padding(scale: 37))
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: padding(scale: 10), left:  padding(scale: 4), bottom: padding(scale: 3), right: padding(scale: 4))
}
```

I fixed it by resting the horizontal insets to the size:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.width - (2 * padding(scale: 4))), height: padding(scale: 37))
}
```

Comment: Can you add your padding function please?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're setting the `itemSize` of `collectionViewLayout` in code, then make sure that the size is valid. Set a breakpoint on the code line where you set the `itemSize`, and check if the size complies to the instruction of the error warning:
*The item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.*

Answer (score -5):

This is what you need:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    //Get frame width
    let width = self.view.frame.width
    //I want a width of 418 and height of 274 (Aspect ratio 209:137) with a margin of 24 on each side of the cell (See insetForSectionAt 24 + 24 = 48). So, check if a have that much screen real estate.
    if width > (418 + 48) {
        //If I do return the size I want
        return CGSize(width: 418, height: 274)
    }else{
        //Get new width. Frame width minus the margins I want to maintain
        let newWidth = (width - 48)
        //If not calculate the new height that maintains the aspect ratio I want. NewHeight = (originalHeight / originalWidth) * newWidth
        let height = (274 / 418) * newWidth
        //Return the new size that is Aspect ratio 209:137
        return CGSize(width: newWidth, height: height)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 24, left: 24, bottom: 24, right: 24)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 33
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 33
}
```