# UICollectionView not fitting within view controller on certain Apple devices

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I made a `UICollectionView` and it displays fine on most types of iPhones. However, on smaller devices like the iPhone SE, the collection view cell runs off the page even though I set my constraints correctly. I get the following error:

```
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus
the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
```

I tried many of the [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437994/swift-2-the-behavior-of-the-uicollectionviewflowlayout-is-not-defined-because?noredirect=1&lq=1) people mentioned such as `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` or setting `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` to `.never` ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596181/why-does-uicollectionview-log-an-error-when-the-cells-are-fullscreen/53806783#53806783)), but so far none of them have worked and the collection view still runs off the page for smaller iOS devices. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the code you've been using to calculate the `collectionViewCell` size.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the size of the `UICollectionViewCell` dynamically, this is done in code and not on the storyboard.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let width = self.bounds.width // This is the width of the superview, in your case probably the `UIViewController`
    let height = 70 // Your desired height, if you want it to full the superview, use self.bounds.height
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: self.bounds.height) // Sets the dimensions of your collection view cell. 
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked! I kept setting the cell width to collectionView.bounds.width instead of the width of the view controller, which was why the cell layout was not changing

Comment: @AhsokaTano Glad you fixed it! When I first started using colloctionViews, I ran into the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution: (Place this code in ViewDidLoad() Function)

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0) //set section inset as per your requirement.
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth/3, height: screenWidth/3) //set cell item size here 
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0 //set Minimum spacing between 2 items
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0  //set minimum vertical line spacing here between two lines in collectionview
collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` method

Just calculate with `minimumInteritemSpacing`, and don't forget about `sectionInset`

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let numberOfCellInColumn = 4.0

    if let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
      let interitemSpace = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing
      let cellWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width - (numberOfCellInColumn - 1) * interitemSpace - flowLayout.sectionInset.left - flowLayout.sectionInset.right) * (1.0/numberOfCellInColumn)
      return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
    }
    return CGSize.zero
  }
}
```

This code return cell size for 4 column on screen