# Xcode11/iOS uicollection view issue

Tags: uicollectionview, ios13, xcode11

*Xcode11/ iOS13* collectioncview not working but *xcode11/iOS12* is working fine and *Xcode10/iOS13* working fine.

issues is,

> "The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined
> because:
>  > 2019-10-29 10:55:17.781597+0530 Storefront[360:20094] the item width
> must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section
> insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right
> values"

I don't where it is exactly occurred.

Comment: please visit it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082726/the-behavior-of-the-uicollectionviewflowlayout-is-not-defined-because-the-cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Xcode11/ iOS13

I had issues with this error message as well. My `CollectionViewCells` were all messed up.

Go into the Interface Builder. Then navigate to the Size Inspector (for the `CollectionView`) and set the Estimated Size to "none".

[image: Estimated Size set to "none"]