# Why are the constraints not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints

**Portrait mode**

[image]

**Landscape mode**

[image]

Tab Bar implemented using `UICollectionView` (CV). In the CV I have added 4 items:

```
addSubview(collectionTab)
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":collectionTab]))
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":collectionTab]))
```

When I change the orientation the constraints are not working. Why? How can I fix it?
I think the size of items is not recalculated when I change the view.

Size of items:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.width/4, height: frame.height)
}
```

Comment: size of items func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: frame.width/4, height: frame.height)
    }

Comment: What is collectionTab? Is that the name of the UICollectionView?

Comment: Yes this is collection view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `invalidateLayout` on the `UICollectionViewLayout` on your `UICollectionView`. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26236679/1311272)

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Comment: When run this function?

Comment: Just implement this in your UIViewController, it gets called automatically

Comment: I think the size of items is not recalculated when I change the view

Comment: are you implementing `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`? You should calculate item size there!

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: frame.width/4, height: frame.height)
    }

Comment: Can you verify that the CollectionView gets a new frame after rotation? Please print the width and height of the CollectionView before and after rotation inside the viewWillLayoutSubviews method

Comment: @maximrad did you print the frames before and after rotation, what are the result?

Comment: Thanks very very much!!

Comment: override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        tabBar.collectionTab.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }